# Trying to know the place before the jaunt

Tags: single-word-requests

Here is the the situation: whenever I plan going out on a vacation to a beach or hill-station, I inquire about the weather, I search for accommodations, I call people who have been there and do other stuff to ensure I get the best out of it.

What am I doing here? What is the process called?

Comment: You are planning your vacation :)

Comment: :-) thanks, but a single term would be even better.

Comment: I doubt you will find one in this case, but let's see.

Comment: Just because English has a large vocabulary doesn't mean there's a single word for **everything**. Even if there is a technical term that hits precisely the note you'd like, the chances that a random group of English speakers would know it are very slight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This process is also called *advance.*  Typically, this has involved visiting the destination ahead of time, but with the advent of the Internet, this is less often the case for low-budget campaigns and low-budget music tours and the like. *Advance* is now anything from a little Internet research and bookings, exactly the process you described, up to an entire team visiting the destination weeks in advance, often both.

> ***advance***, v.trans. to prepare for (an event, esp. the visit of a politician) by visiting the location beforehand in order to arrange security, scheduling, publicity, etc. Also: to visit (a location) prior to an event for this purpose.

Examples:
"I'm doing the advance for my upcoming book tour myself." or 
"I'm going to Spain in August. I'm doing as much online advance as I can."
"The conference is in 2 weeks and there's no one to advance."

There is also this military term which has the notion of a site-visit but the idea of on online reconnaissance or remote reconnaissance in advance of a vacation makes perfect sense in the age of the Internet.

> ***reconnaissance***,n: a survey, inspection, etc., carried out in order to gain information of some kind; the action of carrying out such a survey.

Comment: the advance is having people actually go to the location to prepare, something she hasn't done according to her post.

Comment: +1 for *reconnaissance*, which reminded me of [*reconnoiter*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/reconnoiter): _to examine or survey (a region, area, etc.) for engineering, geological, or other purposes._

Answer (score 2):

I would simply say that you are checking/**scoping** out your options.

> Assess or investigate (something)

What you are doing is trying to form an itinerary.  In heavy slang, you are **itinerarizing**.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing **research.** There is no term specific to a vacation that I know of.

Answer (score 1):

I would say that you're trying to know the [lay of the land](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/lay%20of%20the%20land) before making any definite vacation plans.

> **lay of the land**: the nature, arrangement, or disposition of something, the general state of affairs.

E.g.

[I am going to the Vendée for a break in the summer and am already checking out the lay of the land before booking.](http://services.completefrance.com/forums/completefrance/cs/forums/1861575/PrintPost.aspx)